# ListView changing text color in text

Tags: java, android, listview, colors

Hi im trying to change text color in cell of my list view but i can't because i get

```
11-25 20:22:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-116
11-25 20:22:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
11-25 20:22:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-25 20:22:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-25 20:22:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:225)
11-25 20:22:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.Tab2Fragment.getViewByPosition(Tab2Fragment.java:254)
11-25 20:22:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1338):     at morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.Tab2Fragment$1.run(Tab2Fragment.java:123)
```

this is part code where i try to change color:

```
    int k = cash.size();
                    if(k>0){

                        for(int l=0;l<k;l++){
                            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) getViewByPosition(l+1,listView);
                            if(price<m)
                            {
                                ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.amount)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
}
}
```

when i create linearlayout i have to increment l+1 because if I start from zero i change color at header. This is method I use to change return view:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
here is my adapter. I would add that when my app starts the list is empty, but the new thread which updates color is working.

```
public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super(activity, R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, list);
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



private int mColor = Color.BLACK;

public void setColor(int color)
{
    mColor = color;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
if(convertView == null){
    listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
    convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, null);
    listViewHolder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
    listViewHolder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
    listViewHolder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
    listViewHolder.txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);
    convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
} else {
    listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
listViewHolder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
listViewHolder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
listViewHolder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
listViewHolder.txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));


TextView textViewFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
TextView textViewSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
TextView textViewThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
TextView textViewFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);

textViewFirst.setTextColor(mColor);
textViewSecond.setTextColor(mColor);
textViewThird.setTextColor(mColor);
textViewFourth.setTextColor(mColor);

return convertView;
}

public class ListViewHolder {
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your adapter? The exception is throw because your list view is empty. Did you called notifyDataSetChanged after changing the adapter info?

Comment: You posted the code of the ListViewAdapter, but the adapter that is throwing the exception is the HeaderViewListAdapter

Comment: `View header = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.naglowek_wlasne_spolki, listView, false);
     listView.addHeaderView(header);` thats all about header in my code

Comment: Yes, you're right, the HeaderViewListAdapter is from android. Can you tell me what is the line 254 of Tab2Fragment?

Comment: its from getViewByPosition method `    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
         return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);` i pasted whole this method in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not manage the views outside of the adapter because you don't have any control when the ListView will draw the views or each views are visible.

You should set the color in the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged to notify ListView to redraw the views (calling getView for each visible item).

Basically you are already doing it with the variable mColor of your adapter, you just need to add the call to notifyDataSetChanged after the color is changed to notify the ListView to redraw the views.